# Java - Styling an application

Tags: java

Okay, i am officially scared to ask this question. I am a `PHP` developer that is attempting to learn the language of `JAVA`. My experience limits me to `PHP`, JavaScript and basic `CSS` to develop and style my web apps.

I would like to know, and this is embarrassing, What technology is used to "Style" `JAVA` Applications just like `CSS` is used to "Style" `HTML` & `PHP` applications?

I feel so stupid asking this! Please don't think i am an idiot, i am really good with `PHP`.

I tried to `google` the answer but gained more questions than answers.

Comment: Depends: Webapp or desktop app?

Comment: If you're programming Java servlets, then you can actually just have CSS styling your front end. If you're creating desktop applications, the java SWING library is pretty good.

Comment: @Chris : SWING library OR JavaFX

Comment: Downvoter, explain yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Web Application using Java:

```
Frontend is  same i.e. HTML/Javascript/CSS
Backend Java (from where data you will get, connect with DB etc etc) similar to role of PHP
```

Desktop Application:

```
you can use Java Swing for UI and other API for respective work.
```

Mobile Application:

```
use J2ME API for developing application
UI here is developed using JAVA API(only api that are allowed to use under KVM (kilobyte virtual machine)).
For better look and feel there are frameworks for it.
```

Answer (score 2):

What about JavaFX? As far as I know there are similarities to CSS. However, most of the Java applications are designed  to match the system's look-and-feel. That's why tweaking is not as important as to web pages. If you want to start with that, have a look at Swing components. Be aware that JavaFX will be included in Java 8. So JavaFX may be seen as the next gen GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Basically U use JSP/JSF/HTML for front end . There too you can use  your CSS skills .. That is CSS can be used for styling ...

Comment: that's true if it is a webapplication. but what about desktop apps?

Comment: @ShuhailKadavath `JavaFX 2.0` would be way better if he wants to implement `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing a desktop application, not internet application - as otherwise PHP and especially HTML/CSS would suffice.

Java **Swing** is a cross-platform emulation of GUI components. It has so called ***Look and Feels***, one of which is the System L&F, which under Windows tries to look as the Windows GUI. Another is really cross-platform looking: the Nimbus L&F. And there are other Look-and-Feels, even from third parties.

Start with System or Nimbus Look and Feel.

Besides that one might set default colors/fonts for specific type of things. One may query them with `SystemColor.activeCaptionText` or so. Nice for White on Black.

Inside Swing one uses ***layouts*** to do the layouting. Generally not pixel perfect, but with really cross-platform, with consideration for different buttons, menues and such.

Use a GUI editor; I am always advocating the NetBeans IDE, also for its simplicity. Though eclipse is very nice too.

Use separate classes, do not pack all in a GUI class, as that becomes a maintenance mess.

The text components: JLabel, tooltip, and so on, have ***HTML*** capabilities: `"<html><b>Bold</b><i>Italics</i>"`.